# Just downloaded MacGDBp, unsure how to use it

Tags: php, macos, debugging, xdebug

I just downloaded latest MacGDBp 1.5 but I am unsure how to debug my php scripts through it. There is no documentation or readme on the [website](http://www.bluestatic.org/software/macgdbp/) as well.
Looking for how will I load my Php scripts to debug in it?
Does it always works in conjunction with other IDE like Eclipse?

Currently it only debugs what ever I am debugging with Eclipse.
Thank you

Comment: Start xDebug and MacGDBp on the server and make a request. You should be able to examine the code being run.

Comment: Xdebug is loaded on phpinfo and MacGDBp is on. What do you mean by make a request? Just open a link on the browser?

Comment: Yep, just open something in your browser. However, Xdebug being loaded as an extension does not necessarily mean it's active. You can see whether or not it's active by making a `var_dump` call — if it's styled with colors and tables, it means Xdebug is active.

Comment: I am sure xdebug is active, I am wondering how wil MacGDBp start debugging a file. Also the open option is dimmed in it.